# ios app crash when calling a property with the underscore format

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, properties

I have declared a variable in .h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *var;
```

When i call a property variable using:

```
 _var = sumthing;
```

the app crashes and when i call it as:

```
 self.var = sumthing;
```

it works well.

Is there any difference in these two scenarios?

NOTE: I have not used `@synthesize` as it is not required to write this specifically.

Comment: Why "_var" and "var" must be a identical ?

Comment: Are you using ARC? What crash do you get?

Comment: If you aren't using ARC then assigning directy to the instance variable won't be retaining the object.  Assigning to the property will retain the object.

Comment: So, are you using ARC? if not, you got an answer - an you should also use STRONG instead of RETAIN.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: yes I am using ARC. It says, the variable has been deallocated.

Comment: if you have used  @@synthesize var; you don't need to cal it self.var, just var is enough and if @synthesize var=_var, you will get _var = sumthing;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `self.var` to retain `sumthing` when you are using `@property` so that it calls the setter method internally to retain it. If you are directly assigning it, the setter method wont be called and it will crash when `sumthing` is released.

Basically a `self.var = sumthing;` is equivalent to assigning `sumthing` to `var` and then retaining it(`var = [sumthing retain];`). When you are directly doing it, it just does the assigning part and not the retaining. So when `sumthing` gets released, you will be pointing to a released variable when you use `var` and your app crashes.

If you still want to use it without using `self.var`, you can try with `_var = [sumthing retain];` which could work.

This has nothing to do with synthesize since you dont need to use it anymore. You can skip it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you @synthesized property of your var with _var..?
If not it will directly treat it as var. don't use _var.

Comment: so either i should `@synthesize var = _var;` or i should always use `self.var` instead of `_var`?

Comment: Hmm. If it is from IBOutlet,if we wont @synthasized also it will automatically takes, but where it comes to coding we need to do.

Comment: well, i think `@synthesize` is not required if I directly use `self.var`

Comment: Its works only for updated Xcode version. If we use older versions, we must need to @synthesize  the property. other wise it will moves to crash the application.